# How to style the jQueryUI Datepicker without using any jQuery CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a DatePicker jQuery calendar in my Web App but it is 'transparent' at the moment since I am not using any jQuery CSS theme or similar.

I was wondering what CSS properties should I include in my own CSS so it becomes solid. I have no clue where can I find it.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to use one of the jquery-ui CSS files, the code depends on it for some of the basic layout.

Comment: In that case, how can I override the properties? I guess that should be possible, right?

Comment: Yes, certainly. Just add a `<style>` section after you load the jquery-ui CSS file, and add the appropriate style to the classes you want to customize.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, sorry.  I need to add the section after this?
*<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />*

Comment: Yes. This is basic HTML+CSS knowledge.

Comment: You could also put your modifications in another `.css` file, and load it with a `<link>` tag after the one that loads `jquery-ui.css`.

Comment: Later files override earlier files.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You probably downloaded jQuery UI, if so, you can/can not delete it, but just take the source out of the HTML, include this instead:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```